# Translate/Detect Rectangle portion of Image from Resized Image

Tags: c#, .net, image, algorithm, rectangles

I have a Large size image.Since it takes long to process high res images i resize it keeping the aspect ratio.From the resized image i detect a rectangle and i have the coordinates of the rectangle.

```
 Bitmap ResizekeepAspectRatio(Bitmap imgPhoto, int Width, int Height)
        {
            int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
            int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
            int sourceX = 0;
            int sourceY = 0;
            int destX = 0;
            int destY = 0;

            float nPercent = 0;
            float nPercentW = 0;
            float nPercentH = 0;

            nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
            nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
            if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            {
                nPercent = nPercentH;
                destX = System.Convert.ToInt16((Width -
                              (sourceWidth * nPercent)) / 2);
            }
            else
            {
                nPercent = nPercentW;
                destY = System.Convert.ToInt16((Height -
                              (sourceHeight * nPercent)) / 2);
            }

            int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
            int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

            Bitmap bmPhoto = new Bitmap(Width, Height,
                              PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            bmPhoto.SetResolution(imgPhoto.HorizontalResolution,
                             imgPhoto.VerticalResolution);

            Graphics grPhoto = Graphics.FromImage(bmPhoto);
            grPhoto.Clear(Color.Red);
            grPhoto.InterpolationMode =
                    InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            grPhoto.DrawImage(imgPhoto,
                new Rectangle(destX, destY, destWidth, destHeight),
                new Rectangle(sourceX, sourceY, sourceWidth, sourceHeight),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            grPhoto.Dispose();
            return bmPhoto;
        }
```

Is there a way by which i can translate/Map this rectangle to the Large image so that i get the same area.Im doing this to save time.

***Some clarification:***
I  have a Large Original Image.. i resize it keeping the aspect ratio and using some processing i get a rectangle portion in it( Just the coordinates).Since the Image quality of this portion is not good i need to find a way to map this coordinate to the large image.

Comment: Let me guess, you have a visualizer and the user can move freely to view the content? if that's the case then only resizing a part of it will not be a solution as when the user moves to other area it will not be zoomed and thus you will need to zooming areas on each change, really expensive.

Comment: @Gusman No.. I just have a portion marked in the resized image(small image) i need to translate it to the larger image.Hope im clear now.

Comment: Ok, to get all finally clear, you have: A-the original photo, B-the max size, C-the rectangle you want respect scaled size

Comment: @Gusman No i have a Large Original Image.. i resize it keeping the aspect ratio and using some processing i get a rectangle portion in it( Just the coordinates).Since the Image quality of this portion is not good i need to find a way to map this coordinate to the large image.

Comment: Ok, you need to clarify coordinates and where from/to you want to go. Put an example please and then I can add some code as the matter is really simple, it's just a "rule of three" problem.

Comment: @Gusman There are no specific coordinates .. it varies randomly from image to image.All i have a Large Image,The Resized Small Image and the coordinates of the rectangle in the small image.What i need is a way to map this rectangle to the large image(so that the same portion of the image in the small image rectangle is marked in the larger one).. Hope you got it.. thanks for your help.

Comment: For what you're saying you have a big problem, if the proportions of the image don't fit exactly as the ones of your viewport you can end with a rectangle outside the image, is this correct?

Comment: @Gusman No..You dont have to worry about that at all.All i need is a way to map the portion of image in the small image (rectangle) to the larger one...Im cropping out this portion of the image.. so i need better quality so im doing this.If i crop from small image.. the output will be of low quality.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so if I understand it clear here it is:

You have a viewport in what you select a rectangle and you want to scale this rectangle to the unscaled image.

So we will have a function like this:

```
public RectangleF TranslateScale(RectangleF CropRectangle, Bitmap imgPhoto)
```

First of all what we need is to calculate the multiplier to fit the image on the viewport, exactly like your function:

```
        int sourceWidth = imgPhoto.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgPhoto.Height;
        int sourceX = 0;
        int sourceY = 0;
        int destX = 0;
        int destY = 0;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);
        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;
```

Now that we know the scale percentage we just take the inverse of your function, instead of multiply just divide the rectangle size and position:

```
        CropRectangle.X /= nPercent;
        CropRectangle.Y /= nPercent;
        CropRectangle.Width /= nPercent;
        CropRectangle.Height /= nPercent

        return CropRectangle;
```

And that's it, now you have the rectangle scaled to the original image size, you now can crop that rectangle.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. i will try and get back within a few hours .. Midnight past here..

Comment: this function is not returning the proper translated rectangle